# mongoengine - filter by "OR" on a single field in a single query

Tags: python, mongoengine

Here's a (really) rough example of what I'm looking for - given a document with the following schema:

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, DateTimeField

class Client(Document):
    name = StringField()
    activated_on = DateTimeField(required=False)
```

How would I query it for a client that was never activated or activated before a certain point in time?

In other words, both of the documents would show up in the results if I searched for entries without an activation date or one that occurred before 2016-07-22.

```
{ "name": "Bob Lawbla" }
{ "name": "Gerry Mander", "activated_on": 2016-07-01T00:00:00 }
```

I know I can do:

```
Client.objects(activated_on__lte=datetime.datetime(2016,7,22))
```

and

```
Client.objects(activated_on__exists=False)
```

but how do I combine them into one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Q class](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries) :

```
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q as MQ

Client.objects(MQ(activated_on__exists=False)|MQ(activated_on__lte=datetime.datetime(2016,7,22)))
```

Comment: can you tell me how to filter if field is equal to null ?